# How to create directory inside directory in Dropbox API with objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, directory, dropbox

I know how to create a directory, like:

```
[[self restClient] createFolder: folderName];
```

But if I want to create folder "B" inside folder "A," how would I do that?

Directory hierarchy is:
A > B > c.txt

I can create "A" but I can't create B inside A.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are half done , Just try this

```
[[self restClient] createFolder:@"A"];
```

then

```
[[self restClient] createFolder:@"A/B"];


- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client createdFolder:(DBMetadata*)folder{
    NSLog(@"Meta Data Path %@",[folder path]);
    NSLog(@"Meta Data Filename %@",[folder filename]);
    NSLog(@"Meta has directory %d",[folder isDirectory]);

}
// Folder is the metadata for the newly created folder
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client createFolderFailedWithError:(NSError*)error{
    NSLog(@"Fail Error %@",error);
}
// [error userInfo] contains the root and path
```

[Metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#metadata) and About [Create Folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#fileops-create-folder)